# Process all files in S3 weekly

Tags: java, json, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

What is the best way process all files in S3 in weekly manner?

My bucket contains many json files and what I need: run on all files (one time in week) and parse data of these files for statistic report. For example, group by id and do count by some fields. And result to save in one file, that I'll send to users.

Example:

**INPUT:**

first_json - { id:xxx, messages:["first message", ..., "x message"] }

...

xth_json - { id:xxx, messages:["first message", ..., "x message"] }

...

last_json - { id:yyy, messages:["first message", ..., "x message"]}

*Messages in json file is array of message objects with date, text, who sender and etc...*

**OUTPUT:**

{id:xxx, numOfSentMessages:zzz, numOfReceivedMessages:www}

...

{id:yyy, numOfSentMessages:zzz2, numOfReceivedMessages:www2}

Then for each user will be send email with his statistics: number sent messages, number received messages, frequency by day/hour and etc...

I think in one week number of jsons can be millions files.

Comment: use aws lambda. you can easily configure it to run once a week. then write a code to pull data from s3 an process them.

Comment: alternatively you can use crontab if you use linux. But of course if your computer is off then it wont run

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to do this (depending on what you're actually trying to do!).

**Scheduling**

If you run code on an **Amazon EC2 instance**, you can use `cron` to trigger a script.

If you run code as an **AWS Lambda function**, you can add a schedule to the function.

**Processing**

You did not supply much information about the content of the files and how they should be processed (eg whether each file is individually processed, or if multiple files are processed together).

Some processing options are:

- If the files can be **processed individually**, you can use [S3 Select](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/s3-glacier-select/), which can run simple SQL-like commands over the file, without needing to download the file
- For more **complex queries**, including processing multiple files together, use **Amazon Athena**
- If the files need to be processed with custom code, either run a script on an **Amazon EC2 instance**, or run an **AWS Lambda function** (Note: Lambda has a maximum execution time of 15 minutes)

S3 Select and Amazon Athena can be called from a Lambda function.

**Inventory**

If you have a large number of files (tens of thousands or more), it might be efficient to use [Amazon S3 Inventory](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/storage-inventory.html) to provide a weekly list of input files. You code can then use that list to perform operations.

**Real-time processing**

Rather than processing data as a weekly batch, you could also consider performing **real-time processing when the data is placed in Amazon S3**. You can configure an Amazon S3 Event to trigger an AWS Lambda function when the file is created.

**Sending to users**

Rather than sending a file to users, it is generally better to provide a link back to a file. Your email administrators will thank you!

Regardless, your AWS Lambda function can use **Amazon Simple Email Service (SES)** to send emails. However, you'll need some way of identifying who should receive such notifications.

One option is to send a notification to **Amazon Simple Notification Service (SNS)** and users can subscribe to the message. It could point them to the report (but also consider security of the report).